# How to parse text file

Tags: java

demo.txt :
FD1,true,102400,4000,0.01,103,83.25 
FD0,false,102400,4000,0.01,103,83.25

I want to access each line 1st then from each line i want to access each element and pass this as parameter to a function createFogDevice to perform some action.
like createFogDevice(FD1,true,1024,4000,0.01,103,83.25)

Can anybody help how we can write code for this ?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File());

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] dataPoints = currentLine.split(",");

        String a = dataPoints[0];
        boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(dataPoints[1]);
        // ....
        createFogDevice(a,b,c/*...*/);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("demo.txt"))) {

        stream.forEach(ob->createFogDevice(ob.split(",")));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also you can modify createFogDevice() method to pass Array of String as argument :-

```
private static void createFogDevice(String[] inputParams) {
    // your code goes here
}
```